# Supersedes clause in database structure

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, linq-to-nhibernate

Imagine a database table that looks like this:

```
create table [dbo].[user]
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    currentid int NULL,
    processedby varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    processeddate varchar(50) NOT NULL
    processedaction varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

What I want to do is to setup NHibernate to load it into my user object, but I only want the current version of the object "user" to be brought back.  I know how to do a SQL select to do this on my own, and I feel as if there's something in nHibernate with the usage of triggers and event listeners, but can anyone tell me how to implement the nHibernate repository so I can:

- {Repository}.GetCurrent(id) <- pass it any of the ids that are assigned to any of the historical or the current record, and get back the current object.
- {Repository}.Save(user) <- I want to always insert the changes to a new row, and then update the old versions to link back to the new id.

---

Edit

So, there's some confusion here, and maybe I explained it wrong... What I'm trying to do is this, in regards to always getting the current record back...

```
Select uc.*
FROM User uo
JOIN User uc on uo.currentid=uc.id
WHERE uo.id==:id
```

But, I don't want to expose "CurrentID" to my object model, since it has no bearing on the rest of the system, IMHO.  In the above SQL statement, uo is considered the "original" object set, and uc is considered the current object in the system.

---

Edit #2:

Looking at this as a possible solution.
http://ayende.com/blog/4196/append-only-models-with-nhibernate

I'm honestly being pigheaded, as I'm thinking about this backward.  In this way of running a database, the autoincrementing field should be the version field, and the "id" field should be whatever the autoincrementer's value has at the time of the initial insert.

---

Answer:

I don't want to take @Firo's fury, and I'm not going to remove it from him, as he took me down the right path... what I wound up with was:

1. Created a base generic class with two types given
   a. type of the object's "ID"
   b. type of the object itself.
2. instantiate all classes.
3. create a generic interface IRepository class with a type of the object to store/retrieve.
4. create an abstract generic class with a type of the object to store/retrieve.
5. create a concrete implementation class for each type to store/retrieve.
6. inside of the create/update, the procedure looks like:

   ```
   Type Commit(Type item)
   {
       var clone = item.DeepClone();
       _Session.Evict(item);
       clone.Id = 0;
       clone.ProcessedDate = DateTime.Now;
       if (clone.Action.HasValue)
       {
           if (clone.Action == ProcessedAction.Create)
               clone.Action = ProcessedAction.Update;
       }
       else
       {
           clone.Action = ProcessedAction.Create;
       }
       clone.ProcessedBy = UserRepos.Where(u => u.Username == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name).First().Current;
       var savedItem = (_Session.Merge(clone) as Type);

       _Session.CreateQuery("UPDATE Type SET CurrentID = :newID where ID=:newID OR CurrentID=:oldID")
           .SetParameter("newID", savedItem.Id)
           .SetParameter("oldID", item.Id)
           .ExecuteUpdate();

       return savedItem;
   }
   ```
7. In the delete method, we simply update the {object}.Action = ProcessedAction.Delete

I wanted to do this another way, but realizing we need to eventually do historical comparisons, we weren't able to ask nHibernate to filter the deleted objects, as the users will want to see that.  We'll create a business facade to take care of the deleted records.

Again, much thanks to @Firo for his help with this.

So, with all that, I can finally do this:

```
var result = {Repository}.Where(obj => obj.Id == {objectID from caller}).FirstOrDefault();
if (result != null)
{
    return result.Current;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

and always get my current object back for any requesting ID.  Hope it helps someone that is in my situation.

Comment: You want the logic you have described to be implemented in NH mapping or in your repository class?

Comment: Would like it so that I issue a {repository}.save(object); in my controller, and that somewhere lower in the stack, the feature can be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mapping if you use FluentNHibernate

```
public UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Where("id = currentid"); // always bring back the most recent
    }
}

// in Userrepository
public void Update(User user)
{
    var clone = user.Clone();
    session.Evict(user);  // to prevent flushing the changes
    var newId = session.Save(clone);
    session.CreateQuery("UPDATE User u SET u.currentid = :current")  // <-- hql
        .SetParameter("current", newId)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
}
```

objectgraphs are a lot trickier with this simple code. I would then do one of the following:

- use NHibernate.Envers to store auditing information for me
- explicitly creating new entities in BL code

i once saw an append-only-model doing something like the following

```
// UserBase is there to ensure that all others referencing the User doesnt have to update because user properties changed
class UserBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonDetails> AllDetails { get; private set; }
    public virtual PersonDetails CurrentDetails
    {
        get { return _currentDetauils; }
        set { _currentDetauils = value; AllDetails.Add(value); }
    }

    // same as above
    public virtual ICollection<ConfigDetails> AllConfigs { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserBase User { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<OrderDetail> AllDetails { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<OrderDetail> ActiveDetails { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Add(OrderDetail detail)
    {
        AllDetails.Add(detail);
        ActiveDetails.Add(detail);
    }
    public virtual void Delete(OrderDetail detail)
    {
        detail.Active = false;
        ActiveDetails.Remove(detail);
    }
}

class OrderDetail
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
}

class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        HasMany(o => o.AllDetails);
        HasMany(o => o.ActiveDetails).Where("active=1");
    }
}

// somewhere
public void UpdateTaxCharge(OrderDetail detail, TaxCharge charge)
{
    var clone = detail.Clone();
    clone.TaxCharge = charge;
    detail.Order.Delete(detail);
    detail.Order.Add(clone);
}
```

Comment: feel bad asking, but can't how this works... can you elaborate @Firo?  Where does all of this go, and what do you do about saving an object graph (order => order details => order details tax charge)

Comment: What if you're not using fluent nHibernate, but the *.hbm.xml files?  feel a bit guilty, but didn't specify that I wasn't using fluent yet.  Just getting into nHibernate, as I was more of an avid user of EntityFramework, Linq-to-SQL, and DevExpress XPO Objects before. @Firo

Comment: Should also ask, is your "Clone()" method something that you implemented, or are you using an extension method, etc. to implement that?  I know of .MemberwiseClone(), but never saw a Clone() method in std. c#

Comment: hbm.xml: FNH is easier to write and maintain but it creates hbm behind the curtons -> in xml it would be `<class where="..."`. Clone can be implemented per class or as extension method or mixed eg like DeepCopy here https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Utils/Extensions.cs

Comment: the code i posted is the general idea to make it explicit in the code that you use and append only model. Otherwise you fight the framework and suffer from a leaky abstraction.

Comment: gotcha.  I was trying to avoid the fluid route for now only because I want to keep the setup and deployment simple.  Will look into.  Thanks @firo.

Comment: @Firo... the id==currentid logic doesn't work.  When you build out the supersedes clause in a database, you have to do a self-join and then select based on the id of 5.  Going to research, and then post the update to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell NHibernate what exactly SQL it should generate when persisting and loading an entity. For example you can tell NHibernate to use a stored procedure instead of a plain SQL statement. If this is an option for you I can farther elaborate my answer.

Comment: we were trying to avoid the use of TSQL stored procs, as there is some unrest at the client site as to whether they stay on SQL server, or convert to something else.